# Responsive Images (Bootstrap)

Tags: responsive-design, frontend, responsive

I am pretty young in FE Developing so I wanna ask what kind of problems can i face in the future with this class ".img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto;" in Bootstrap. Can I safely give this class to every image? And what will be your advices